# Link to a selection in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

When the user clicks a link, I want to send them to another page with a dropdown, pre selected corresponding with the link they clicked.  For instance, if they select a link to "merchandise", I want to send them to another page with a drop down selected for "merchandise, rather than the other select categories like "all", "sales", "architecture" etc.  How could I do this?

Comment: php and html would work, css to make it a little more beatiful, and add a little javascript!

Comment: It depends on what JavaScript framework you are using. There are ways to do it with JQuery, and ways to do it with AngularJS. Which are you using?

Comment: is possible to do it using url attributes and jquery

Comment: @eugene1832 I am using Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding parameters to the first page links and then parsing them on a second page to set the selected option in the select input, try this example:

page1.html

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="page2.html?category=merchandise">Merchandise</a>
<a href="page2.html?category=all">All</a>
<a href="page2.html?category=sales">Sales</a>
<a href="page2.html?category=architecture">Architecture</a>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var selectedCategory = getUrlParameter("category");
        $('select').val(selectedCategory);
    });

    function getUrlParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }    

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<select>
<option value="merchandise" >Merchandise</option>
<option value="all" >All</option>
<option value="sales" >Sales</option>
<option value="architecture" >Architecture</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
      localStorage.setItem("category",$(this).text());
});
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="submit.php">Merchandise</a>
<a href="submit.php">All</a>
<a href="submit.php">Sales</a>
<a href="submit.php">Architecture</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

submit.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>

    window.onload = function() {
        $('select option[value="' + localStorage.getItem("category") + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body > 
<select>
<option value="merchandise" >Merchandise</option>
<option value="all" >All</option>
<option value="sales" >Sales</option>
<option value="architecture" >Architecture</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```